# Access DB on a server outside LAN

Tags: mysql, port, database, local-area-network, timeout

On my pc I have installed mysql server on port 3307 and there is a database that runs on it. I need to access it outside of my local network

In particular, I am interested in accessing from a net core service that uses the following connection string:

```
Server=[Public Server IP];Port=3307;Database=[DBName];User Id=user;password=[password];
```

Initially, I opened the my.ini to verify the existence of the binding address and possibly change it from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0, however the instruction is not present in the file.

In the DB, I then created a new user "user" and execute the following query to grant privileges.

```
GRANT ALL ON [DBName].* TO 'user'@'%'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

by doing this, I can correctly access the database from devices connected within the same network (using LAN IP in connection string, instead of public IP).

I then went into my router settings and, in the "port activation" section, I added a new line:

incoming protocol: tcp
outgoing protocol: tcp
incoming port: 3307
Outgoing port: 3307

when I try to run my service from outside LAN, after a few seconds I get the "Connect Timeout expired" exception.

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: Usual question #1: Does your router actually have a public IP address?

Comment: I don't want to say anything wrong, but I would say yes. I get it from whatismyipaddress

Comment: External websites can't really tell you that – e.g. they can't distinguish whether the address is your computer's or your router's (the NAT gateway hiding the computer's own private address), and likewise they can't distinguish whether the address is your router's or a CGNAT gateway's at the ISP (same thing one level up). Check the router's own status page to see if it shows exactly the same address or if the "WAN address" is a private one.

Comment: yes, in the "state and support" page of router the "ip addess" is the same

Comment: Your router also has to have a reservation set in DHCP for the computer where the MySQL database is running, so that its IP does not change, and the "port forwarding" section of your router's setup also has to forward port 3307 to that IP.

Comment: Same IP address is a good sign, considering how many LANs are behind CGNAT these days. The next thing to check might be whether the DB machine sees the actual packets (using tcpdump or Wireshark).

Comment: I installed wireshark and it doesn't seem to see anything. in the Static DHCP - Home Network section I added the device that hosts the database.

Comment: Solved... it was enough to move the rule from the port activation section to the port association section, specifying the local IP. Thank you all

Comment: .Andrea Welcome to SF.  I appreciate your sharing of your Solution.  We help people make their WordPress, MySQL or MariaDB hosts deliver query results faster.